# How to get a value of an element with name XML PHP parse

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to get a value of an element line with a name odds1 (1.6). Any idea how?

The XML looks following:

```
<Match id="1">
<Name>Charlotte Independence v Richmond Kickers</Name>
<Date>07/26/2017 19:00:00</Date>
<Bet type="PS" id="1">
<line name="points1">+2.5</line>
<line name="odds1">1.6</line>
<line name="points2">+2.5</line>
<line name="odds2">2.2</line>
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Where's the PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
$string = '<Match id="1">
<Name>Charlotte Independence v Richmond Kickers</Name>
<Date>07/26/2017 19:00:00</Date>
<Bet type="PS" id="1">
<line name="points1">+2.5</line>
<line name="odds1">1.6</line>
<line name="points2">+2.5</line>
<line name="odds2">2.2</line>
</Bet>
</Match>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->Bet->children() as $child) { 
    $val = $child->attributes();
    if($val == "odds1") {
        echo $child;
    }
}
```

In above, I have assigned your xml to a variable $string.
If it's in a file you can use simplexml_load_file.
Then I have iterated through children of Bet and captured the attributes by using function attributes(). This function provides the attributes and values defined within an xml tag.

Rest is just checking if attribute is odds1 and then capturing its value.

Comment: Or if you want to be lazy: `$xml->Bet->line[1];`. I mean, he did ask for the specific value :P +1 from me